# Kernel error after updating to Spyder 4.1

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I updated spyder to 4.1 in anaconda through (conda update spyder), and it doesn't  work unless I open it from the anaconda prompt, otherwise it shows this error:

An error ocurred while starting the kernel
The error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1209, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
>   kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 267, in start_kernel
>   self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, env=env, **kw)
>
> File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 211, in _launch_kernel
>   return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
>
> File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
>   proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>   restore_signals, start_new_session)
>
> File "C:\Users\anwar\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>   startupinfo)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

and in the corner, it still shows spyder 3.7

Comment: have the same issue.

Comment: Don't use the desktop short cut. **Use Anaconda Navigator or Promt to open Spyder**. And wait for the update to resolve the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem is a duplicate of [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11819) and it is fixed in our **4.1.1**, released in March 19th 2020.

Comment: Thank you so much Carlos!  So now I come back with the Spyder 4.01 and wait for the 4.1.1 version.

Comment: @BillLe, please upvote my answer so I can close other related questions.

Comment: Just tested the update and the kernel is starting up now

Answer (score 0):

Rollback Spyder 4.0.1 in python 3.7 environment and that should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

ACK, I have observed the same.

Another problems:

1) There is not possible to close the outline panel.
2) Profiler is unable to profile, for example, 
   this program (something with i/o redirection):

```
def sum_of_harmonic_series(n):
    s = 0
    for k in range(n, 0, -1):
        s += 1 / k
    return s

N = int(input("N: "))  # replace this line with N = 10000 as a workaround  
print('sum = ', sum_of_harmonic_series(N))
```

Comment: Hi Slawek,
Unfortunately, this is not an answer. It's more of a comment or a 'me too'. It looks like you have your own question in your comment. Create a new question and if you believe it's related to the original question then you can link it with a comment to the original question.