# Updated from Spyder version 4.01 to 4.1 , then Loading Spyder, getting "An error occurred while starting the kernel"

Tags: spyder

I just updated Spyder from version 4.01 to 4.1 today, 3/18/2020. Then I loaded spyder and get an error as "An error occurred while starting the kernel" with the error list as below.  Could anyone help me to fix this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1209, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 267, in start_kernel
self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, env=env, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 211, in _launch_kernel
return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 135, in launch_kernel
proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 729, in **init**
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\Ben\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1017, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731255/i-updated-spyder-to-4-1-and-it-is-not-working. Please upvote my answer there so I can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: I updated Spyder with the version 4.1.1, today, 3/19/2020.  It solved the problem of "An error occurred while starting the kernel", which caused from the update Spyder 4.1  Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm really glad!! Thanks for letting me know about it.